# Calling dynamic jQuery plugin with dynamic parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we need to dynamically construct plugin calls such as

```
$('#myDiv').myPlugin({a:'a',b:'b'});
```

will be something like:

```
function funcCallBuilder(selector, func, opts){
  //dynamically construct plugin call here
}
```

using:

```
funcCallBuilder('#myDiv', 'myPlugin', {a:'a',b:'b'});
```

Can someone point out the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand the question, but if you simply want your first and third code snippet to have the same effect, just use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply):

```
function funcCallBuilder(selector, func, opts){
    func.apply($(selector), [opts]);
}
```

or, if you really want to pass the function as a string instead of a function object (not much point IMHO):

```
function funcCallBuilder(selector, func, opts){
    $.fn[func].apply($(selector), [opts]);
}
```

Comment: yep, .apply( ) should do it for you. Although, I think it should be $.fn[func].apply( $(selector), opts );

Comment: $.fn[func].apply($(selector), opts); worked for me!  Thank you so much Tgr.

Comment: Should have used [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or arrayified the argument; fixed now. If you are sure you only need one argument, the simpler syntax `$(selector)[func](opts)` should work too.